How to work out angle at which the object is moving
PictureHow do I work out the angle that an object is moving and not pointing. I am not old enough to be smart so if you do use Sin(theta) functions please explain what it is doing because I don't just want to copy and paste and would much rather understand what is happening, thanks.
Here is a diagram:




You'd have to explain a bit more what you mean.  Do you mean an angle say above the flat surface of the ground?  Or do you mean looking from overhead which "direction" it is going (rather like north, west south, east, sort of thing) ... ?  You can add images on this site, just make a drawing on paper then photo it.

Does this answer your question? How to calculate the angle between a line and the horizontal axis?

We'd need more info, but note that basically objects in unity have a .velocity property
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html
The velocity is a vector which tells you exactly what you want to know.
As I mention in a comment, nobody reading would have a clue what you mean specifically by "angle", so click edit and add more info to your question.
TERMINOLOGY:
PS, as a game programmer, just like being a pilot, as a starting point you need to be incredibly familiar with terms like

Heading

Course

Track

Bearing


and so on.  (Just use the internet.)
Anyway .velocity has the info you need. You could google things like "Unity3D convert .velocity to angle".
